# Clone lttng via http

Tags: git, lttng

I am trying to clone lttng by running the command

```
git clone git://git.lttng.org/lttng-modules.git
```

and what i get is

```
$ git clone git://git.lttng.org/lttng-modules.git
Cloning into 'lttng-modules'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.lttng.org:
git.lttng.org[0: 167.114.142.139]: errno=No such file or directory
```

I have tried to replace `git://` with `http://` and a username and password is requested. Could you please help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Bogdan.

Comment: It worked fine for me with `git://`. Try again or investigate why your computer cannot connect to `git.ttng.org`. It is a network issue.

Comment: i am behind a firewall which i cannot modify.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Default-Port for the git Protocol is closed on your firewall. Try use https instead of the git protocol

```
git clone https://git.lttng.org/lttng-modules.git
```

This has given the following result to me:

```
$ git clone https://git.lttng.org/lttng-modules.git
Cloning into 'lttng-modules'...
remote: Counting objects: 8044, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2616/2616), done.
remote: Total 8044 (delta 5855), reused 7474 (delta 5330)
Receiving objects: 100% (8044/8044), 1.79 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5855/5855), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

If still not works you have eventually a too old git version. A good idea is to use a newer portable version of git (for Windows Users for example https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitportable/)

Comment: i used http and i have to give a username and password which i dont know.

Comment: I've cloned this repository right now with this command. Everything worked. My Log: 

$ git clone http://git.lttng.org/lttng-modules.git
Cloning into 'lttng-modules'...
remote: Counting objects: 8044, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2616/2616), done.
remote: Total 8044 (delta 5855), reused 7474 (delta 5330)
Receiving objects: 100% (8044/8044), 1.79 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5855/5855), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

Comment: This is what i get

$ git clone http://git.lttng.org/lttng-modules.git
Cloning into 'lttng-modules'...
Username for 'http://git.lttng.org':

Comment: specify the http protocol like me in the code snippet

Comment: I did exactly like you and I have to put a username and password. I have git 1.9.5 if this helps. I cannot get Another version.

Comment: same ...

$ git clone https://git.lttng.org/lttng-modules.git
Cloning into 'lttng-modules'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.lttng.org/lttng-modules.git/': Failed connect to git.lttng.org:443; No error

Comment: I'm sure you find a newer, portable Version of git on the internet. check with that.